# SP 2010 Select an Asset dialog returns "Cannot display Web Part"

Tags: 2010, publishing-site

I am new to SharePoint administration, so I decided to set up a new 2010 environment using Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Sharepoint 2010 on a stand-alone machine.  This will let me "play around" with SharePoint without compromising the real environment. I was following along with a lesson from LearnNowOnline on Web Content Management, and created a new site.  Everything was going fine until I tried to add a graphic from the Site Collection Images. For some reason, I get "Unable to display this Web Part" when I click on any entry in the Select an Asset dialog.  The steps I took are outlined below.

What am I missing here?  I have wiped the environment and reinstalled and still get the same error, so I don't thing the problem is with the installation.

Thanks for your assistance
Art.

steps to reproduce:
1. from Sharepoint Central Administration, create a site collection
    Name: Demo Error
    URL: /sites/DemoErr
    Template: Publishing Portal
2. when top level site is created, click on link to open it
3. from the site actions menu, select new page
    name: showme
4. change the page layout to Image on the Left
5. click on the "Click here to insert a picture from Sharepoint" in the Page Image web part his will open the Edit Image Properties -- Webpage Dialog
6. Click on the Browse button for the Selected Image line
    - this will open the Select an Asset -- Webpage Dialog
7. click on Site Collection Images entry in the left column
    - the associated link in the right column references: /sites/DTF/SiteCollectionImages/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx

At this point, I receive the following message in the right column:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft Sharepoint compatable HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID: (guid appears here)

I get a similar error if I click on any other asset in the Left column.

Comment: Robert is correct - this is the same issue noted in his link but from the UI perspective.  using wusa /uninstall /kb:2844286 resolved the issue.

Comment: This issue is starting to get pretty loud this week :)

Comment: Yeah, major screwup, and in the middle of at least the Swedish summer holidays